# Dynamic change the property name in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, properties, typing

I would like to have a typing (No need implementation) which can help me to add some dynamic string in the class

For example:

```
class Dog() { 
  bark: () => void
  eat: () => void
}
// But actually in runtime, bark is nobark; eat is noeat
// That's why I would like to have such type
inteface Husky extends addSomethingInClass(Dog, 'no') {} 
// Husky.nobark && Husky.noeat can be autocompleted
inteface Corgi extends addSomethingInClass(Dog, 'go') {} 
// Corgi.gobark && Corgi.goeat can be autocompleted
```

I wonder if it can be

Thanks for help

Comment: you would have to use a decorator for that

Comment: You can't do sting manipulation like this in the type system unfortunately. Best you can do is write a custom tool (that uses the compiler API) to generate the interfaces

Comment: @Ken but why? What do you want to use this for?

Comment: @mleko Actually I am using Vuex with namespaced option and want to have autocomplete via this.$store.actions.bark to call the method. But with namespaced option, the action name will be this.$store.actions[{moduleName}/bark]. That's why I want to make a short cut to add the moduleName before action to have autocomplete in the component

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Can I request some example for that? Thanks 
This one sounds ok too

Comment: @Ken You can request it :) I'm not sure I have time to provide it right now, though. Also you should know the compiler API  is very likely to have breaking changer from version to version, so make sure you really, really , really need this and can't find an alternate architecture.

Comment: @Ken I'll try to write something today, but it would be something similar to this to find the classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795939/typescript-source-parse-get-interface-related-to-certain-react-class/50796637#50796637

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thank you so much :)